# How to create qt widgets dynamically in qml?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to create a QMainWindow(`MainWindow`) in a qml Window(`InitialForm`)). There is a button in the `InitalForm`, and when I click it, I hope a `MainWindow` can be dynamically created and show. Do something like

```
    MainWindow* mainWindow = new MainWindow(GameType::PVE);
    mainWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    mainWindow->show();
```

I tried several ways:

1. Create a normal function to create `MainWindow` and show, then call `qmlRegisterSingletonType<QObject>(...)`.
2. Create a factory method and wrapper in a class(`MainWindowFactory`), then call

```
    qmlRegisterSingletonType<MainWindowFactory>(
        "Kmc", 1, 0, "MainWindow",
        [](QQmlEngine*, QJSEngine*) -> QObject* { return new MainWindowFactory(); });
```

In way 1, I don't know how to pass arguments to constructor of `MainWindow`.

In way 2, a `MainWindow` does show after I clicked button in `InitialForm`, but it just disapper at once, and the entire application exit successfully.

Comment: Is your real problem that you just don't know how to call a C++ function from QML?

Comment: @JarMan No, actually, I know how to call C++ function from QML at least two ways. The one is create a instance in `main`, then use `setProperty` to pass it to QML, but I don't want to create a local variable unless I have to. The other one is using `qmlRegisterSingletonType<QObject>(...)` just like what I described in quesion.

Comment: There are many ways to create components in QML, but, my preferred way is using a model, eg. `Repeater { id: repeater; model: 0; delegate: MainWindow { } }` and by increasing repeater.model, you get new instances of your component, and, conversely, they get destroyed when repeater.model decrements. There's also Instantiator. Then there's Loaders and finally, the methods described by Qt: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html

Comment: @StephenQuan However, I guess it might be hard to pass arguments to constructors of `MainWindow` to create various objects.

Comment: No, why? If you're using Repeater you can pass the arguments via the model.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a demonstration of how you can use `Repeater` to dynamically create an`MainWindow` component. A `ListModel` is used to pass parameters to new instances of `MainWindow`.

I created a mock implementation in `MainWindow.qml` based on `ItemDelegate`, but, you could use the real C++ implementation here.

Clicking on the "Create Random" button will append a new item to the ListModel. Which will instantiate a new MainWindow with a random position and color. Clicking on the new MainWindow will cause the corresponding entry to be removed from the ListModel causing the MainWindow to be destroyed.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Repeater {
        model: ListModel { id: listModel }
        delegate: MainWindow { }
    }
    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Create Random"
        onClicked: {
            listModel.append( {
                p: Math.random() * 500,
                q: Math.random() * 500,
                w: 100,
                h: 50,
                r: Math.random(),
                g: Math.random(),
                b: Math.random(),
            } );
        }
    }
}

// MainWindow.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
ItemDelegate {
    x: p
    y: q
    width: w
    height: h
    background: Rectangle { color: Qt.rgba(r,g,b) }
    text: index
    onClicked: listModel.remove(index)
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAC+nicjVKxbsIwEN3zFSempEKBDl3crXRBKlJh6ewkJ8fCsYM5GiqUf+/FpIFCS3tDdO/8/PLsZ13VzhMsabnT+TrS32A6c5a8M9voVSqEQwRcK6xREvoedlW5Ao2AF72lRdfCAXQhwAy4HaiMUPF2AQup7Zu2hWuYfiQcv087ImfP5KXNS+e3aY6W/zu3AmrpuR8IhHsSMJr5zhisJItWo2HV2ZnhwyA7Oml2NfhLZV2jLeKL9a7qziiVqQ+icQJ38DCdjq94m3/yGgH3P81Lwfzrsb+QvWaoPxnZTUYLyeMw+IqhjaLJ5CyhdFOZi7fx61OZE1bPfcr9he45sdB8CNiEptEF8ZGbAErUquQAy4Ayma+VdzvLea0wJ2mVYSHInXF8HUtKvcpk7MdqnCW94+MDYKu4D/gs8lPIHiv3jnFgJVH7CeG/zZc=)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I might need a real c++ example. I registered `MainWindow` via `qmlRegisterType<MainWindow>(...)`. However, there is a error reported at `MainWindow{}`: Element is not creatable.

Comment: Probably easier to look at someone else's work. For instance in https://github.com/stephenquan/qmlonline6 I register SyntaxHighlighter in src/main.cpp with its C++ implementation in https://github.com/stephenquan/qt-toolkit and I use it in QML in https://github.com/stephenquan/qmlonline6/blob/5fd4bb15a754a42b267a193d7da1b962939a8cfa/qml/MainPage.qml#L104